Background colour change on website by click on button
I am trying to master JS and jQuery, but I can't resolve this task.
Task : 1 click on button, we are getting black background on website, 2 - click, we are removing all changes and back to default what was before.
It getting black background, but second click does not work.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="button">Button for test</button>

script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        function on_contrast(){
                  $('body').css('background', 'black');
            
    function off_contrast(){
                  $('body').css('background', 'black').off();
        };

        $('#button').click(on_contrast);
        $('#button').click(off_contrast);
    }); 
</script>

I tried many times and different options, but looks like I do not understand logic in some places.

Firstly, the code in your question has some syntax errors. Next, I don't think off() does what you think it does.

But your button is also running both functions each time it's clicked.

Thank you! How can I fix that?

I would create a css class for the dark mode styling. Use a single function to toggle that class on and off.

Also, it's considered poor programming practice to change styles using JavaScript. Styles (and their mods) should be defined in CSS (stylesheet) and switch those classes using jQuery .toggleClass() or JS's .classList.toggle().

Also, where do you close the on_contrast function with a } ? Learn to use Developer Tools, those errors/typos can be spotted pretty quickly. Since you still have not, please take a [tour] to learn how this site works (and get a welcome badge!).

This question is similar to: How to change background color of datepicker form in Materialize design using jQuery?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="button">Button for test</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let isBlack = false;

        $('#button').click(function () {
            if (isBlack) {
                $('body').css('background', '');
            } else {
                $('body').css('background', 'black');
            }
            isBlack = !isBlack;
        });
    });
</script>



I added a variable isBlack to keep track of the current state of the background color. It toggles between true and false each time the button is clicked.
The if-else block checks the value of isBlack. If it's true, the background is set back to the default (empty string '' resets it to whatever the default was before). If it's false, the background is set to black.
After setting the background color, the code toggles the value of isBlack using isBlack = !isBlack;

You don't need to keep track of anything if you use .toggleClass()

You also don't need to keep track if you use classes as that "keeps track" for you - other than simpler .toggleClass, you can then use .hasClass("darkmode")

As other comments mention you don't need an extra variable to track state. The background value is stored by the browser variable document.body.style.background

If you use CSS for styling and set the class name of the body, you can start to style any element on the page according to the state.


document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
});
body.dark {
  background-color: black;
}

body.dark button {
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}
<button type="button" id="button">Button for test</button>





You're not closing properly your functions body with }
jQuery's .off() method is well documented here and it's a counter method to the .on() which you'll learn how to use in this example
Avoid the .click() method, use rather the preferred .on() method to assign event handlers like $("#button").on("click", toggle_contrast);
If you want to learn now how to off an Event handler, use whenever you want i.e: $("#button").off("click", toggle_contrast); (will stop listening (unsubscribe) to click events for that specific callback function)
You don't need two functions, just use .toggleClass() method to toggle a specific modifier CSS class from a target element
styles are best defined in your stylesheet, not disseminated in your JS file, use CSS to define your .dark{} styles and toggle it using JavaScript



.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
<button type="button" id="button">Button for test</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope
  
    function toggle_contrast() {
      $("body").toggleClass("dark");
    }

    $("#button").on("click", toggle_contrast);
    
  });
</script>
<!-- Closing </body> goes here -->



And yes, jQuery is nowadays not that much necessary for those simple tasks. You can rewrite the above in pure JavaScript without the overhead of an entire JS library (like jQuery — or any other)


.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
<button type="button" id="button">Button for test</button>

<script>
  const elBody = document.querySelector("body");
  const elButton = document.querySelector("#button");

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    elBody.classList.toggle("dark");
  };

  elButton.addEventListener("click", toggleTheme);
</script>
<!-- Closing </body> goes here -->




Since you used jQuery so toggleClass will help you to achieve your goal.
Just add Dark theme CSS with a class and then on button click toggle this class over body
here is the simple solution:


$(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('dark');
  });

});
.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button">Button for test</button>




TesterMetatest "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's How does accepting an answer work?. Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"
